# dropbox icon disappears only for some users, while dropbox still loads

Tags: unity, dropbox

On Ubuntu 12.04 I have two users: for both Dropbox is installed and starts when logging in, but only one of the two can see the actual (white) Dropbox icon in top right tray: what is the problem with the other one?